# How to deduplicate table rows with the same date and keep the row with the most current date stamp?

Tags: sql, soql

A client (e-commerce store) doesn't possess a very well-built database. For instance, there are many users with a lot of shopping orders (=different IDs) for exactly the same products and on the same day. It is obvious that these seemingly multiple orders are in many cases just one unique order. At least that's what we have decided to work with to simplify the issue. (I am trying to do a basic data analytics.)

My table might look like this:

```
|     Email         |  OrderID  |    Order_date    |    TotalAmount   |
| ----------------- | --------- | ---------------- | ---------------- |
|customerA@gmail.com|     1     |Jan 01 2021 1:00PM|       2000       |
|customerA@gmail.com|     2     |Jan 01 2021 1:03PM|       2000       |
|customerA@gmail.com|     3     |Jan 01 2021 1:05PM|       2000       |
|customerA@gmail.com|     4     |Jan 01 2021 1:10PM|       2000       |
|customerA@gmail.com|     5     |Jan 01 2021 1:14PM|       2000       |
|customerA@gmail.com|     6     |Jan 03 2021 3:55PM|       3000       |
|customerA@gmail.com|     7     |Jan 03 2021 4:00PM|       3000       |
|customerA@gmail.com|     8     |Jan 03 2021 4:05PM|       3000       |
|customerB@gmail.com|     9     |Jan 04 2021 2:10PM|       1000       |
|customerB@gmail.com|    10     |Jan 04 2021 2:20PM|       1000       |
|customerB@gmail.com|    11     |Jan 04 2021 2:30PM|       1000       |
|customerB@gmail.com|    12     |Jan 06 2021 5:00PM|       5000       |
|customerC@gmail.com|    13     |Jan 09 2021 3:00PM|       4000       |
|customerC@gmail.com|    14     |Jan 09 2021 3:06PM|       4000       |
```

And my desired result would look like this:

```
|     Email         |  OrderID  |    Order_date    |    TotalAmount   |
| ----------------- | --------- | ---------------- | ---------------- |
|customerA@gmail.com|     5     |Jan 01 2021 1:14PM|       2000       |
|customerA@gmail.com|     8     |Jan 03 2021 4:05PM|       3000       |
|customerA@gmail.com|    11     |Jan 04 2021 2:30PM|       1000       |
|customerA@gmail.com|    12     |Jan 06 2021 5:00PM|       5000       |
|customerA@gmail.com|    14     |Jan 09 2021 3:06PM|       4000       |
```

I would guess this might be a common problem, but is there a simple solution to this?
Maybe there is, but I certainly don't seem to come up with one any time soon. I'd like to see even a complex solution, btw :-)

Thank you for any kind of help you can provide!

Comment: How do you know they are "the same order"? What are the other tables involved? Please provide schema and some sample data for all tables involved.

Comment: If they're duplicate orders, why do they have different order ids and different order dates? It seems that you have a fault in your line of business system, or you are misunderstanding the data. *(What if a customer legitimately makes two orders on the same date?)* ***Exactly*** what rules do you require be applied to remove the 'problem' rows?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```
WITH
indata(Email,OrderID,Order_ts,TotalAmount) AS (
          SELECT 'customerA@gmail.com', 1,TO_TIMESTAMP( 'Jan 01 2021 01:00PM','Mon DD YYYY HH12:MIAM'),2000
UNION ALL SELECT 'customerA@gmail.com', 2,TO_TIMESTAMP( 'Jan 01 2021 01:03PM','Mon DD YYYY HH12:MIAM'),2000
UNION ALL SELECT 'customerA@gmail.com', 3,TO_TIMESTAMP( 'Jan 01 2021 01:05PM','Mon DD YYYY HH12:MIAM'),2000
UNION ALL SELECT 'customerA@gmail.com', 4,TO_TIMESTAMP( 'Jan 01 2021 01:10PM','Mon DD YYYY HH12:MIAM'),2000
UNION ALL SELECT 'customerA@gmail.com', 5,TO_TIMESTAMP( 'Jan 01 2021 01:14PM','Mon DD YYYY HH12:MIAM'),2000
UNION ALL SELECT 'customerA@gmail.com', 6,TO_TIMESTAMP( 'Jan 03 2021 03:55PM','Mon DD YYYY HH12:MIAM'),3000
UNION ALL SELECT 'customerA@gmail.com', 7,TO_TIMESTAMP( 'Jan 03 2021 04:00PM','Mon DD YYYY HH12:MIAM'),3000
UNION ALL SELECT 'customerA@gmail.com', 8,TO_TIMESTAMP( 'Jan 03 2021 04:05PM','Mon DD YYYY HH12:MIAM'),3000
UNION ALL SELECT 'customerB@gmail.com', 9,TO_TIMESTAMP( 'Jan 04 2021 02:10PM','Mon DD YYYY HH12:MIAM'),1000
UNION ALL SELECT 'customerB@gmail.com',10,TO_TIMESTAMP( 'Jan 04 2021 02:20PM','Mon DD YYYY HH12:MIAM'),1000
UNION ALL SELECT 'customerB@gmail.com',11,TO_TIMESTAMP( 'Jan 04 2021 02:30PM','Mon DD YYYY HH12:MIAM'),1000
UNION ALL SELECT 'customerB@gmail.com',12,TO_TIMESTAMP( 'Jan 06 2021 05:00PM','Mon DD YYYY HH12:MIAM'),5000
UNION ALL SELECT 'customerC@gmail.com',13,TO_TIMESTAMP( 'Jan 09 2021 03:00PM','Mon DD YYYY HH12:MIAM'),4000
UNION ALL SELECT 'customerC@gmail.com',14,TO_TIMESTAMP( 'Jan 09 2021 03:06PM','Mon DD YYYY HH12:MIAM'),4000
)
,
-- need a ROW_NUMBER() to identify the last row within the day (order descending to get 1.
-- can't filter by an OLAP function, so in a fullselect, and WHERE cond in the final SELECT
with_rank AS (
  SELECT
    *
  , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY email,DAY(order_ts) ORDER BY order_ts DESC) AS rank
  FROM INDATA
)
SELECT
  *
FROM with_rank
WHERE rank = 1;
-- out         Email        | OrderID |      Order_ts       | TotalAmount | rank 
-- out ---------------------+---------+---------------------+-------------+------
-- out  customerA@gmail.com |       5 | 2021-01-01 13:14:00 |        2000 |    1
-- out  customerA@gmail.com |       8 | 2021-01-03 16:05:00 |        3000 |    1
-- out  customerB@gmail.com |      11 | 2021-01-04 14:30:00 |        1000 |    1
-- out  customerB@gmail.com |      12 | 2021-01-06 17:00:00 |        5000 |    1
-- out  customerC@gmail.com |      14 | 2021-01-09 15:06:00 |        4000 |    1
```

Comment: What if a customer makes two actual orders (none duplicate) on the same date?